# Determine the two-term expansion for large roots of the transcendental equation $\tan(x) =\frac 1x$

Tags: asymptotics, perturbation-theory

For this problem, I was given a hint that when $x$ is large, $\frac 1x$ is nearly zero, and $x \sim n\pi$ where $n$ is a large integer.

Initially tried the taylor expansion, but that didn't work out.

I then assumed that since $x$ is large that $\frac 1x \sim \epsilon$ ? I ran into issues once I started to solve the problem and thought maybe that wasn't the correct approach either.

Any hints/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: First, prove that this equation has exactly one solution $x_n$ in the interval $\left]-\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n,\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n\right[$ when $n \geqslant 1$. Then, the inequality $-\frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n \leqslant x_n \leqslant \frac{\pi}{2} + \pi n$ implies that $x_n = \pi n + \mathrm{O}(1)$. Set $y_n = x_n - \pi n$, which is bounded. By periodicity of $\tan$, we have $\tan(y_n) = \tan(x_n) = \frac{1}{x_n} = \frac{1}{\pi n + y_n} \rightarrow 0$. It implies that $y_n \rightarrow 0$ so $\frac{1}{\pi n + y_n} = \tan(y_n) \sim y_n$. Deduce an equivalent of $(y_n)$ and continue to get order $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=n\pi+\delta$. Show that $\tan x=\tan\delta\sim1/(n\pi)\to0$ as $n\to\infty$, which then justifies $\tan\delta\sim\delta$. Conclude from there.